# Change LineThickness in xtracharts legend

Tags: devexpress, legend

We had this problem 6 months ago and after a brief query on Devexpress forums we found out that they added this as a planned feature. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q538236

There isn't any progress after 6 months and I wanted to ask it here if anyone could solve this by implementing a solution by their own.

Is there a way to change the LineThickness in the Xtracharts legend?

Comment: What about hiding the legend and creating your own?